# how to display all error messages in the form header in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I need to display all the messages at the top of the form and I need to implement the custom error for fields like email and phone number.

**index.html**

```
<form name="adminForm" ng-submit="addAdmin()" novalidate>
```

> all error messages need to be displayed here

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': adminForm.firstName.$touched && adminForm.firstName.$invalid }">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="admin.first_name" ng-maxlength="255" required>

    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="adminForm.firstName.$error" ng-if="adminForm.firstName.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': adminForm.lastName.$touched && adminForm.lastName.$invalid }">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="admin.last_name" ng-maxlength="255" required>

    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="adminForm.lastName.$error" ng-if="adminForm.lastName.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': adminForm.email.$touched && adminForm.email.$invalid }">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="admin.email" ng-maxlength="255" required>

    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="adminForm.email.$error" ng-if="adminForm.email.$touched">
        <div ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**messages.html**

```
<p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
<p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
<p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
<p ng-message="email">This needs to be a valid email</p>
<p ng-message="pattern">This needs to be a valid number</p>
<p ng-message="equals">Password must be same</p>
```

I'm looking for any possible solution or a reference to other possible solutions.

**Reason** : I'm finding difficulty in implementing unit tests for this(noob), so i think a single error message can make it easy for testing.
Thanks!

Comment: how about moving your error messages block there.?

Comment: I thought about that, but how should I display errors for all fields, like I should specify fname.$error || lname.$error || ... like that ?

Comment: yeah..like the error messages blocks stays the same but you just basically move your error blocks at the top? Would that solve your problem?